# Reading folders recursively in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, sys

The purpose of this program is to recursively look through all the files and directories in a root directory to find any matches of a key phrase (named file in main method). My main issue is that I cannot figure out how to get into the subdirectories and make sure I loop through all of the files and directories in it, and then continue doing so until I've went through all directories in the tree that started from the root directory.

Here is my current code.

```
import os
import sys

def search_dir(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(path)):
        for f in files:
            if file in f:
                print("File : {}".format(os.path.join(root, f)))
        for d in dirs:
            if file in d:
                print("Dir  : {}".format(os.path.join(root, d)))

def main(file, path):
    print("Starting search for '{}'\n".format(file))
    search_dir(path)
    print("\nDone Searching")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv)!=3:
        print("Usage: python find_file.py [path] [file]")
    else:
        path, file = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
        main(file, path)
```

I've tried changing directories using os.chdir(new_path) but I end up running into problems as I get lost on when to change directories back etc.  I feel as though there is a way to recursively use the search_dir function, but after much thought I cannot execute it correctly.

Comment: I probably will get marked down, but I realized after I posted this that os.walk already goes through the entire tree.  So, the function using os.walk does not have to be recursively used. Maybe someone could then clarify what exactly os.walk does, as reading up on the fucntion didnt make that clear to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import os

def search_dir(root, search):
    for root, _dirnames, fnames in os.walk(root):
        for fname in fnames:
            fpath = os.path.join(root, fname)
            with open(fpath) as infile:
                if any(search in line for line in infile):
                    print("Search term found in", fpath)


if _name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv)!=3:
        print("Usage: python find_file.py [path] [searchTerm]")
    else:
        path, search = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
        main(file, search)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could loop through files as well in this way, and furthermore this helped me understand how to look through files, not just at the titles.  I realize my post was slightly ambiguous, but I just need to find if the key phrase exists in the file or directory names.